# In C# what does $ before and after a Class or Namespace Identifier mean?

Tags: c#, identifier

The C# Identifier rules specify that a name must begin with a Letter or Underscore but the code below works without error. Even the code display function on StackOverFlow below does not think names with starting or ending $'s are valid.

```
namespace $safeprojectname$
{
    [ExportCodeRefactoringProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof($saferootidentifiername$CodeRefactoringProvider)), Shared]
    internal class $saferootidentifiername$CodeRefactoringProvider : CodeRefactoringProvider
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a template value

Comment: Visual Studio uses `$` for replacing variables in templates in a lot of places, but that's not valid c#. Where exactly do you think that code works?

Comment: What makes you think that "works without error"? it certainly doesn't even compile for me... are you sure you're actually compiling it? Is it possible that this is actually a template that is being run through a pre-processor, but is not actually C#? Even if I spoof the attributes and base class, I get no fewer than 25 compiler errors from that code

Comment: So the question was solved, but there is another option that I'd like to mention for people finding this question in the future: there are actually some characters which are allowed in names in IL, but are not legal C#, such as `+`, `<`, `>` and `$`. The C# compiler uses them to generate names for things like generic and anonymous types. See for example this site explaining the process for auto implemented properties: https://wouterdekort.com/2013/10/08/desugaring-auto-implemented-properties/ So if you see these names you may be looking, for example, at a decompiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I was looking at a template file that produced C# not a C# source file.